# Why is DestroyWindow blocked?

Tags: c++, winapi, message-loop

I create a window and message loop in the child thread.
When I sent a custom message through `PostMessage`, when I called `DestroyWindow` in the thread, `DestroyWindow` blocked and did not trigger WM_DESTORY, so the message loop thread cannot exit normally.
I tried `PostThreadMessage`, In addition, I tried to use closewindow. But the problem is that WM_DESTORY is not triggered after calling `DestroyWindow`, not the `PostMessage`.
Message loop thread is still running and window handle is valid, why? I worked hard for a few days and couldn't find the reason, thank you very much.

Destroy window:

```
#define WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP (WM_USER+8600)
mfxStatus CD3D11Device::DeleteRenderChildWindow()
{
    LOG(LS_INFO) << "Intel D3D11Render, Enter DeleteRenderChildWindow, HWND:" << m_hChildHwnd;

    //SetParent(m_hChildHwnd, NULL);
    if (m_hChildHwnd){
        LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Intel D3D11Render, DeleteRenderChildWindow, HWND:" << m_hChildHwnd;
        PostMessage(m_hChildHwnd, WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP, NULL, NULL);
    }
    
    if(m_pChildWindowMsgThread)
        m_pChildWindowMsgThread->Wait();

    MSDK_SAFE_DELETE(m_pChildWindowMsgThread);
    MSDK_SAFE_DELETE(m_pCreateFinishEvent);
    LOG(LS_INFO) << "Intel D3D11Render, Leave DeleteRenderChildWindow, HWND:" << m_hChildHwnd;

    return MFX_ERR_NONE;
}
```

Create window:

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK CD3D11Device::ChildRenderMsgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        LRESULT lResult = 0;
        switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Intel D3D11Render ChildRenderMsgProc, PostQuitMessage, HWND:" << hwnd;
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        case WM_SETCURSOR: {
            break;
        }
        default:
            lResult = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        }
    
        return lResult;
    }
    
    HWND CD3D11Device::ThreadCreateChildWindow(){
        HMODULE hInstance = nullptr;
        BOOL result =
            GetModuleHandleExA(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS |
                GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
                reinterpret_cast<char*>(&DefWindowProc), &hInstance);
    
        if (!result) {
            LOG(LS_ERROR) << "[ThreadCreateChildWindow]GetModuleHandleExA failed.";
            return 0;
        }
    
        // Register the host window class. See the MSDN documentation of the
        WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {};
        wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = &ChildRenderMsgProc;
        wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
        wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.lpszClassName = _T("Render Window Class");
        //wcex.style |= CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW &~WS_CAPTION &~WS_SYSMENU;
    
        // Ignore the error which may happen when the class is already registered.
        RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    
        RECT rcClient = { 0 };
        GetWindowRect(m_HandleWindow, &rcClient);
        // Create the host window.
        HWND hChildWindow =
            CreateWindowW(_T("Render Window Class"), _T("MiniRender"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 0,
                0, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, m_HandleWindow, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
        if (!hChildWindow) {
            LOG(LS_ERROR) << "[ThreadCreateChildWindow]Create child window failed.";
            return 0;
        }
    
        ShowWindow(hChildWindow, SW_SHOW);
        SetRenderChildHwnd(hChildWindow);
        m_pCreateFinishEvent->Signal();
        LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Intel D3D11Render, ThreadCreateChildWindow, HWND:" << hChildWindow;
    
        return hChildWindow;
    }
```

Message loop thread:

```
unsigned int CD3D11Device::ChildWindowMsgThread(void* ctx){
        CD3D11Device* pD3D11Device = static_cast<CD3D11Device*>(ctx);
    
        HWND hChildWindow = NULL;
        if (pD3D11Device) {
            hChildWindow = pD3D11Device->ThreadCreateChildWindow();
        }
    
        if (hChildWindow == NULL){
            return 0;
        }
        
        MSG msg;
        BOOL result;
        while ((result = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0) {
            if (result == -1) {
                LOG(LS_ERROR) << "Intel D3D11Render, ChildWindowMsgThread, GetMessage failed, HWND:" << hChildWindow;
                continue;
            }
    
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP) {
                LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Intel D3D11Render, ChildWindowMsgThread, recv WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP, HWND:" << hChildWindow;
```

> //It's blocking up here

```
                DestroyWindow(hChildWindow);
            }
            else {
                PostMessage(pD3D11Device->GetParentHwnd(), msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
            }
    
            LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Intel D3D11Render, ChildWindowMsgThread, GetMessageing, HWND:" << hChildWindow;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: When the application blocks. Hit the Break All in the Debugger. Check the thread that tryies to call DestroyWindow and observe the Call Stack.

Answer (score 0):

A window has a thread affinity. Only the thread that created the window can destroy the window (and receive and dispatch messages for the window).  This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow):

> A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread.

Comment: Thanks in advance.   
DestroyWindow is called in the thread that creates the window. You can see that DestroyWindowis in CD3D11Device::ChildWindowMsgThread, when receive custom message of "WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP". When I need destory this window, I postmessage "WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP" to the message loop.

Comment: Per the `DestroyWindow()` documentation: "*If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*" What are `DestroyWindow()` and `GetLastError()` actually returning? Are you SURE `DestroyWindow()` is actually being called? The code is posting `WM_QUIT_MSG_LOOP` to `m_hChildHwnd`, but where is `m_hChildWnd` being assigned? In `SetRenderChildHwnd()`? The code shown is hardly a [mcve]